# Can not import random with python2

Tags: python

In Python 2 I can not import `random`. The error indicates an OS function is not implemented, but it does list the function.

The OS is Arch Linux on kernel 3.14.79-1-ARCH and the server is arm based cubox-i.

```
# python2
Python 2.7.13 (default, Apr 24 2017, 20:01:05)
[GCC 6.3.1 20170306] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import random
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 885, in <module>
_inst = Random()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 97, in __init__
self.seed(x)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 113, in seed
a = long(_hexlify(_urandom(2500)), 16)
OSError: [Errno 38] Function not implemented
```

Guessing that there is a missing dependency, any clues?

---

Doing the same on an x86 rig also running arch has no issue.
Also imports `random` OK with Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

solved by downgrading to python2-2.7.13-1. 
Not sure if it is a packaging issue or incompatibility with the ancient kernel this thing has to run.